# How to setup node physics body shape to bounding box

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a scene node:

```
let node = SCNNode()
```

And I want to set node physics body shape to bounding box.
It seems that:

```
node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
```

setup the **Convex** shape type, but I need bounding box. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different SceneKit geometry shapes as a BBox container:

```
let node = SCNNode()

let boundingBox = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 2))

node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, 
                                 shape: .init(node: boundingBox, options: nil))
```